# React array why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two React components, one which is creating a new array on button click and then is sending that array via a function to another component which is mapping and outputting a bulleted list. But instead of displaying a bullet for each item in the array the second component is mashing them together.

First component function:

```
export default class SvcList extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props)

   this.state = {
      servicesArr: []
   }
 }

  changeSelectionsArray = (id) => {  
    this.state.servicesArr.push(id)
    // THIS IS THE FUNCTION SENDING THE ARRAY TO SECOND COMPONENT
    this.props.reviseServicesArray(this.state.servicesArr)  
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div><button id="something" onClick={() => this.changeSelectionsArray(id)}>Click Me</button></div>
    )  
  }
}
```

This is working. A console.log shows this output I am getting from the component:

```
["5bd97355-50d8-4a06-aced-025c8cc587f3", "5bd97403-ae5b-4c90-92cb-130f86154e27"]
```

So I bring this array to my second component via props, and when I console.log the props I am getting the exact array shown above. Here is the second component:

```
export default class SvcDisplay extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props)
  }     

 render() {

  const { servicesArr } = this.props;

  const serviceDisplay = servicesArr.map((item, i) => (
    <li key={i}>{item}</li>
  ));

    return(
      <div>
        <ul>{serviceDisplay}</ul>      
      </div>  
    )  
  }
}
```

The output is all being mashed together as a single bullet, like so:

```
- 5bd97355-50d8-4a06-aced-025c8cc587f35bd97403-ae5b-4c90-92cb-130f86154e27
```

instead of individual bullets. If I added this line to the second component render function above the map function it works perfectly:

const servicesArr = ["5bd97355-50d8-4a06-aced-025c8cc587f3", "5bd97403-ae5b-4c90-92cb-130f86154e27"];

Why is this happening?????

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)? It's e.g. not quite clear where you get `id` from in your code. You should also not mutate your state array by pushing to it.

Comment: Does it help when you include the UL? `const serviceDisplay = (
  <ul>
    {servicesArr.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>{item}</li>)}
  </ul>
);`

Comment: HMR thanks but it didn't help. I also made revisions as Taz742 mentioned below and still having same output.

Answer (score 0):

Because this.state.array.push() is wrong syntax.
Also if you want to use updated state, you need to use callBack from after setState.

```
changeSelectionsArray = (id) => {  
    let { servicesArr } = this.state;
    servicesArr.push(id);

    this.setState({
        servicesArr,
    }, () => {
        this.props.reviseServicesArray(this.state.servicesArr)  
    })
}
```

Or:

```
changeSelectionsArray = (id) => {  
    this.setState({
        servicesArr: [...this.state.servicesArr, id]
    }, () => {
        this.props.reviseServicesArray(this.state.servicesArr)  
    })
}
```

Or:

```
...
```

Or:

```
...
```

Comment: Tried both and still getting same results. Also removed the array from state and just added to blank array and still same result.